# Failed pod clean up in running K8s Job

Tags: kubernetes

I have a long running k8s indexed job (with multiple job having ~5k pods each ). These jobs are run with `RestartPolicy=Never` (one of the limitations when using [podFailurePolicy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/pod-failure-policy/)). We observe a lot of pods in errored state for extended time (in some cases >6h). Is there a setting that I could use to speed up the garbage collection of these failed pods?

`RestartPolicy=Never`, means each index failure creates a new pod, leaving behind older pods in `Errored` state.

Update: The job already has `ttlSecondsAfterFinished` set to 10mins, but this doesn't seem to help in this scenario.

K8s version: 1.26.3

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
kind: Job
...
spec:
  ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 60  # <-- this will delete the job and associated pod after 1 minute.
```

Comment: Thanks but, the job already has ttlSecondsAfterFinished set at 10 mins. I update the question with this info.

Comment: Can you post the job spec to the question and further elaborate what you mean by "errored state".